# How to remove element from 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 2d array like this:

```
var rawData = [
    [1325347200000, 60], [1328025600000, 100], [1330531200000, 15], [1333209600000, 50]
];

//MEMORY
mem.push([
    iteration,
    memory.usage / (1024*1024)
]);
```

that keeps growing. I want to limit the size to 20, so I want to remove the **oldest** element in the array. I tried this but remove one element but keeps growing

```
//Remove first
if(iteration % 20 === 0) {
    rawData = rawData.splice(1);
}
```

Comment: Use `splice(-20)` to get the last 20 items from the array

Comment: [You could use `shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element in the array.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What about `if(iteration > 20) {`

Comment: @mplungjan to be fair, the code they posted is quite enough to understand the issue, and it shows an attempt and what is going wrong as well.

Comment: @JonasW. nope, only 1 arg is [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the rest are optional

Comment: Yeah `if(iteration > 20)` works but I dont know if 1 is the oldest or newest element

Comment: @SterlingArcher - assuming 1325347200000 is a timestamp I do not see where iteration comes in

Comment: What is `mem`??

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an own push method that leftshifts the whole array:

```
class LimitedArray extends Array {
  constructor(max, ...args){
     super(max);
     this.push(...args);
  }

  push(...els){
    for(let i = els.length; i < this.length; i++)
          this[i - els.length] = this[i];
    for(let i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
       this[i + this.length - els.length] = els[i];
  }
}
```

So one can do:

```
 const cache = new LimitedArray(20);
 cache.push(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);
cache.push(22);
```

---

If you really want to do that "inline", you can do:

```
 mem.push([1,2]);
 if(mem.length > 20) mem.shift();
```

---

Or if its not accurate and mem might be longer than 21:

```
mem.push([1,2],[3,4]);
if(mem.length > 20) mem.splice(0, mem.length - 20);
```

As suggested in the comments already, that can be simplified to:

```
mem.push([1,2], [3,4]);
mem = mem.slice(-20);
```

however that might be less performant and less memory efficient.